# Importing csv into mongodb using PHP code

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

Im using MongoCollection::batchInsert() to insert csv data into mongodb,

```
<?php

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://192.168.1.7:27017");

$collection = $mongo->test->cartoons;
$row = 1;
 $handle = fopen(dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/images/importcsv/upload.csv', "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
       echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
       $row++;
       $users = array();
       for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo 'data--'.$data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
       $users[] =$data;
       var_dump($users);
       $collection->batchInsert($users);
    }
?>
```

the above code inserts data in Mongo Collections as two separate arrays one line for header(CSV header) and another one is for data.

[image]

Now i want to merge the CSV header with data as like below to import in mongo,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c10f355b9e5cf00200014d"), "Name" : "Dhanam R.", "DOB" : "12-Aug-80", "Age" : "80" }
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the question?

Answer (score 2):

Really this question could use some Googling but this time only, what you do is take the first row of the CSV:

```
 $columns = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ',');
 $nrColumns = count($columns);
 for ($i=0; $i < $nrColumns; $i++)
 {
    if(array_key_exists($columns[$i], $columnsArray)){
        $columnsArray[$columns[$i].$col_inc] = $i;
        $col_inc++;
    }else{
        $columnsArray[$columns[$i]] = $i;
    }
 }
```

And use that to compare to the index of what you have in `$c`:

```
 $user = array();
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      $user[$columnsArray[$c]] = $data[$c]
      echo 'data--'.$data[$c] . "<br />\n";
  }
```

and then you use `$user` to add to the array:

```
$users[] =$user;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create CSV file in Mongo Db using php code given below:-
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();

// connect to mongodb
$mongo = "172.00.22.00:27017";
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://$mongo");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Unable to connect with mongodb");
}

$db = $conn->nexg_tmp;

//header('Content-Type: application/csv');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
//header('Pragma: no-cache');
//$regex = new MongoRegex("/^LIV/"); 
//$where = array('code' => $regex);

$col1 = $db->ASSETS;
$col2 = $db->BITFRAME;
//$records = $col1->find($where)->limit(5);
//$records = $col1->find()->limit(1500);
$records = $col1->find();

//$records = $col1->find(array('code' => 'LIV002'))->limit(5);

$csvarr = array();
$fp = fopen('example.csv', 'w');

$headings[] = "Code";
$headings[] = "CH/VOD CODE";
$headings[] = "CH/VOD NAME";
$headings[] = "VOD/LIVE";
$headings[] = "URL1";
$headings[] = "URL2";
fputcsv($fp, $headings);

foreach ($records as $val) {

    $csvarr = array();
    $csvarr['code'] = $val['code'];
    $csvarr['charge_code'] = $val['charge_code'];
    if (empty($val['name'])) {
        $val['name'] = $val['channel_name'];
    }

    /* if(empty($val['type'])){
      $val['type'] ="VOD";
      } */

    $csvarr['name'] = @$val['name'];
    $csvarr['type'] = @$val['type'];

    $rec_BitFrameCol = $col2->find(array('code' => $val['code'], 'type' => $val['type']));
    foreach ($rec_BitFrameCol as $k => $BitFrameval) {
        $csvarr['url' . $k] = $BitFrameval['url'];
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $csvarr);
}
echo "Completed Successfully..";
?>
```