# How to import CSV data into mongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, csv

I have a CSV file with data like the following:

```
cn,mail,telephonenumber,uid
admin,,,
"Isaac Newton",newton@ldap.forumsys.com,,newton
"Albert Einstein",einstein@ldap.forumsys.com,314-159-2653,einstein
```

I would like to make it so that in mongodb, my data would look like the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c10f355b9e5cf00200014d"), "Name" : "admin", "Email" : "Null", "Phone Number" : "Null", "User ID" : "Null" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c10f355b9e5cf00200014d"), "Name" : "Isaac Newton", "Email" : "newton@ldap.forumsys.com", "Phone Number" : "Null", "User ID" : "newton" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c10f355b9e5cf00200014d"), "Name" : "Albert Einstein", "Email" : "einstein@ldap.forumsys.com", "Phone Number" : "314-159-2653", "User ID" : "einstein" }
```

For all the null fields, they can just not exist either, but wanted to make it clear that the fields are missing.

The only information I've found is in this forum, but uses the deprecated mongo PHP driver documentation.

[Importing csv into mongodb using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834396/importing-csv-into-mongodb-using-php-code)

However, here's some code that I've written to insert a single document.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mongo_location = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($mongo_location);
echo "Connected to ".$mongo_location;
  $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

  $doc = array(
      'id'      => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID,     #Generate MongoID
      'name'    => 'harry',
      'age'     => 14,
      'roll_no' => 1
  );

  $bulk->insert($doc);
  $mongo->executeBulkWrite('schooldb.student', $bulk);    # 'schooldb' is database and 'student' is collection.
?>
```

As you can see, the way you connect to the mongodb is different now.

Comment: What's the exact problem you are facing? Are you struggling with parsing that file, or inserting the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's a solution:**

1. Install a CSV to JSON package with Composer like this:

`composer require ozdemirburak/json-csv`

2. Place a *students.csv* file at your project's root. Contents:

```
name,email,phoneNumber,userID
admin,,,
Isaac Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,,newton
Albert Einstein,einstein@ldap.forumsys.com,314-159-2653,einstein
```

3. Place a *students.php* file at your project's root. Contents:

```
<?php
use OzdemirBurak\JsonCsv\File\Csv;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$csv_filename = 'students.csv';
$csv = new Csv($csv_filename);
echo 'Loaded CSV file: ' . $csv_filename . '<br>';

// Convert CSV to JSON then JSON to Array.
$array = json_decode($csv->convert(), true);

$mongo_location = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($mongo_location);
echo 'Connected to ' . $mongo_location . '<br>';

$mongo_bulk_write = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
foreach ($array as $doc) {
  // MongoDB ObjectID will be automatically generated.
  $mongo_bulk_write->insert($doc);
}
// 'schooldb' is database and 'student' is collection.
$mongo->executeBulkWrite('schooldb.student', $mongo_bulk_write);
echo 'Populated MongoDB database';
?>
```

4. Open *students.php* in your Web browser. Check MongoDB.